# mysql 5.6.21 update statement is very slow when log_bin is on

Tags: mysql, performance, logging, bin

my update statement is

```
update ptest set amount = amount - 2000 where id = 2
```

table ptest is

```
CREATE TABLE `ptest` (
  `id` bigint(19) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `developerId` bigint(19) DEFAULT NULL,
  `appId` bigint(19) DEFAULT NULL,
  `caller` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `callerDisplay` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `called` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `calledDisplay` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `startTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `endTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `callTime` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `callId` varchar(32) NOT NULL ,
  `billingTime` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `callResult` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=200001 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

when system variable log_bin was set to: log_bin=mysql_bin, jmeter test result is 237.4 transaction/second .
when log_bin is comment out #log_bin=mysql_bin, jmeter test result is 3500.2 transaction/second .

on both setting the insert rate is similar, about 8000 transaction/second.

why log_bin has terrible performance impact on mysql?
how can I improve update performance when log_bin is turn on?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no. You can't improve the performance while binary logging is on. I think this is one of the biggest tradeoffs in MySQL. The long answer comes from an article by Baron Schwartz, the lead author of the MySQL performance blog:

> Enabling the binary log reduces MySQL’s performance dramatically. It
>   is not the logging itself that’s the problem — writing the log is
>   usually not much additional work. It’s ensuring consistency and
>   durability that is expensive. Flushing it to disk adds an fsync call
>   for every transaction. And the server performs an XA transaction
>   between InnoDB and the binary log. This adds more fsync calls, and
>   causes mutex contention, and prevents group commit, and probably other
>   things that aren’t coming to mind now.

You can read the [full article here](http://www.percona.com/blog/2010/10/23/mysql-limitations-part-2-the-binary-log/).